# Why Grad CAM need resize to 224 x 224

Tags: conv-neural-network

I implemented grad CAM as per https://github.com/1Konny/gradcam_plus_plus-pytorch.

however, when I run the grad cam with different image size, I get dramatically different CAM. The model is trained on the 50x50 images.

GradCAM with 224x224 image

[image: GradCAM with 224x224 image]

GradCAM with 50x50

[image: GradCAM with 50x50]

Answer (score 0):

You need to scale the image to match the size of the input image, which in your case is 50 x 50. However, if your model was trained on 224 x 224 sized images (say in a pre-trained network), I would stick to inputting 224 x 224 sized images.

Comment: Hi, I'm using a squeeze net but I'm not using the pre-trained one, just the architecture. My model was train on 50x50 sized image, so I'm not quite sure why I need to up it 224x224?

Comment: Well, it may be that somewhere in your implementation of squeeze net the model is either upsampling input images to 224 x 224 or it's adding padding around the input images so that it matches 224 x 224. In the Selvaraju 2019 paper, they say that "L
Grad-CAM is first upsampled to the input image resolution using bilinear interpolation", so check you're using bilinear interpolation as well. There could be some other error in Grad-CAM implementation - don't always trust other people's code!